# Доступ к DOM popup.html расширения Chrome

Tags: chrome-extension

Уважаемые коллеги, вопрос следующего характера:
Я пишу расширение для хрома. Как нужно подключить js-файл и как в нем получить доступ к DOM popup.html?
Имеется такая разметка popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>xdParser v1.1</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="starter" type="button" value="Запустить парсер" onclick="console.log('sd');" />
  <a href="javascript:alert()" id="astarter" onclick="javascript:console.log('sd');">Запустить парсер</a>
  <div id="resultbox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Но никакой реакции от js на клики на этой странице я не получаю.

Answer (score 1):

В расширениях Google Chrome есть запрет на исполнение inline JavaScript. 

Поэтому обработка событий вида `onclick="javascript:..."` не работает.

Вам необходимо подключать JS код в виде отдельного внешнего файла

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```